# Disappearing Navigation Bar when typing into Search Bar

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have here a Menu with a Navigation Bar, Search & Scope Bar, and a table view:

[image: Shows Scope BAr]

The issue is that when I type into the search bar this happens:

[image: Dissapering Navigation Bar]

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? I'm doing all of this in Stroyboard.

Comment: Do you know that it's possible to edit your images so that (1) they are smaller and (2) you include only the important part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 2 things here,

1) If you don't want your UISearchController to animate over your navigation bar then you can set

```
yourSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

2) You can set `definesPresentationContext` so that your search controller only will be on top.

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0):

There's property on your UISearchController called `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation`. Just set it to `false`.